# Java - how to read Google Appengine backup file entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've backed up an appengine datastore entity to Google Cloud Storage, and want to access the records in those files for conversion to another system.

I've tried using https://github.com/google/leveldb and https://github.com/dain/leveldb to read the files, but the APIs don't recognize the backup files as a database.

There's a gist at https://gist.github.com/hernanliendo/8155436, but the Files API is disabled, as I've noted in the comments.

Has anyone had any success reading the appengine backup files using Java?